# Ionic 2 serve --lab windows phone not appear

Tags: windows-phone, ionic2

When I run command ionic serve --lab only Andoid and Ios platforms appear. I add windows platform to my Ionic project, but it still not appears:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the normal screen of the lab.

[image]

Then click in platforms, and select the platform what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Lab View only shows Android and iPhone devices.
and we only add platform to our project when we want app build of required platform, it has nothing to do with testing app on browser.

Comment: https://youtu.be/SvDJM9h2dBw?t=1443 In this video, there is windows device but  I don't know how to add it. Do you have any idea how to do that?